# Create Android Service which no "Task Killer" application can kill

Tags: android, service

I want to create service which no "advance task killer" can kill, or even if kills it would restart again.

I tried below scenarios which didn't work :

1. START_STICKY
2. Registering receiver for SMS (unfortunately it won't work on
   tablets)

Can anyone suggest with code ?

Comment: You can irritate the user until they no longer make use of the app, which is one way to keep them from killing it, but you cannot prevent root from terminating your service.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the onDestroy() method of Android services, which would restart your service once it is killed.

```
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
            context.startService( serviceIntent );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks "Cyber_rookie", will try this too. Also does the "MyService.class" is the class calling itself ?

Comment: it is not valid approach !!

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. Every time the service gets killed, it recalls itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
try to use `START_STICKY` and make the service run on foreground by using `startForeground (int id, Notification notification)`

**Reason:**
by doing so the system considers it to be something the user is actively aware of and thus it is not a candidate for killing even when low on memory.

**Reference:**
Have a look at [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for reference

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: Thanks Mehul. I will try that as well. Thanks for ur help